# Actual android permissions much more liberal than defined permissions in manifest

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-permissions

My manifest only has these 3 permissions:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Yet when I publish my APK to the Play Store it lists:

This app has access to:

- In-app purchases
- Identity

  - find accounts on the device
- Location

  - approximate location (network-based)
- Photos/Media/Files

  - modify ordelete the contents of your USB storage
  - read the contents of your USB storage
- Other

  - use accounts on the device
  - full network access
  - view network connections

It never needed all of these permissions. The last time I updated my target SDK was 20, now it is 22. Does this have something to with it? (My min sdk remains at 14). I have been using Google Analytics from the start. I have also had in app purchases from the start.

This is very annoying because now my users will think I am accessing their media and location which I am absolutely not.

Comment: It's not unlikely this is because of your project's dependencies and Manifest Merging. If you have dependencies with a lower targetSdkVersion than your own project, some permissions may be added because they were implicit on an older platforms and have since then been changed to be explicit. [See more here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger#TOC-Implicit-permissions-addition) and [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/manifest-merge.html#implicit-permissions).

Comment: See also [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/25/hey-where-did-these-permissions-come-from.html).